# Azure Service Bus Topic, not all subscriptions trigger from C# Azure Function Method

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have Service Bus Topic with 3 subscriptions, further got the HttpTrigger Azure Function that Create Service Bus Message. I am new to Service Bus and my understanding is all three Subscriptions should trigger when I create Message in Azure function but in my case only one of the subscriptions does trigger and not other two. I have checked in Azure Service Bus Explorer and cannot see any dead-letter neither so my assumption is the other two subscription didn't trigger.

`Azure Function`

```
[FunctionName("CreateRecord")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "POST")] HttpRequest req
      , [ServiceBus("MyTopicA", Connection = "MyTopicConnection")] IAsyncCollector<Message> servicebusMessage
        )
    {
       //remaining code

        await servicebusMessage.AddAsync(ringGoExemptionMessage);
    }
```

`Azure Service Bus the one trigger'

```
[FunctionName("ProcessToElastic")]
 public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("MyTopicA", "exemptiontoelastic", Connection = "MyTopicConnection")]
        Message message, string lockToken, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ExecutionContext context,
        [ServiceBus("providerexemptionreceivednotification", Connection = "MyTopicConnection")] IAsyncCollector<Message> reScheduleMessages)
    {
      //
    }
```

`Service Bus the once not Trigger`

```
[FunctionName("ProcessToDb")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("MyTopicA", "exemptiontoazuredb", Connection = "MyTopicConnection")] Message message, string lockToken,
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ExecutionContext context,
    [ServiceBus("providerexemptionreceivednotification", Connection = "MyTopicConnection")] IAsyncCollector<Message> reScheduleMessages)
    {

    }
```

not sure really what I missing or how to debug ServiceBus locally, meaning I can debug Azure Function but not service bus??

Comment: Please check the filtering rules defined on the Subscriptions not receiving the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Gaurav-Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri). Posting your suggestion as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues.

As the Service bus is not not trigger and only the function is triggering we need to check the filtering rules that are defined on the subscriptions which are not receiving messages.